# Chocolatey fails to download unity (via travis)

Tags: unity-game-engine, travis-ci, chocolatey

Since [Travis now supports building on Windows](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-10-11-windows-early-release) (at least to a certain degree), I'm playing around with getting a `Unity` project built on a windows machine.
While trying various changes to the `Travis` config, I had two builds which were able to install `Unity` (but did nothing else). Once I had a config ready for trying to build with unity, `Chocolatey` failed to download `Unity`.

Did I personally (through the `Travis` slave) hit something like a daily download limit (and I always get the same slave IP)? Or is this a result of several people downloading unity through `Travis` too often?

Since I am able to manually download the file through the link provided in the logs, I would exclude a unity server issue as a reason.

Here's the failing `Travis` log:

```
$choco install unity
Chocolatey v0.10.11
Installing the following packages:
unity
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading unity 2018.3.11... 100%
unity v2018.3.11 [Approved]
unity package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Downloading unity 64 bit
  from 'https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/5063218e4ab8/Windows64EditorInstaller/UnitySetup64.exe'
ERROR: The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/5063218e4ab8/Windows64EditorInstaller/UnitySetup64.exe'. Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." 
This package is likely not broken for licensed users - see https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-private-cdn.
The install of unity was NOT successful.
```

And for reference, the succeeding one (more than an hour earlier).

```
choco install unity
Chocolatey v0.10.11
Installing the following packages:
unity
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading unity 2018.3.11... 100%
unity v2018.3.11 [Approved]
unity package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Downloading unity 64 bit
  from 'https://download.unity3d.com/download_unity/5063218e4ab8/Windows64EditorInstaller/UnitySetup64.exe'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\travis\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\unity\2018.3.11\UnitySetup64.exe (557 MB).
Download of UnitySetup64.exe (557 MB) completed.
Hashes match.
Installing unity...
unity has been installed.
  unity may be able to be automatically uninstalled.
 The install of unity was successful.
  Software installed as 'EXE', install location is likely default.
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that there is a new rate limiting function on Chocolatey.org (this was turned on [on the 26th November 2018](https://twitter.com/chocolateynuget/status/1067152225955442688)) the HTTP Error code that is returned when this is in play is 429, rather than 403.  As a result, I don't think that this is what is causing you problems.

There is a troubleshooting article regarding the 403 HTTP Status code [here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting#im-getting-a-403-unauthorized-issue-when-attempting-to-use-the-community-package-repository).  I would suggest following through with the recommendations there, which could be due to some of the following reasons:

> - You have a proxy that you need to configure
> - It is being blocked in your organization
> - We broke something (this is the least likely reason)
> - CloudFlare has blocked your IP due to reasons (99% of the time, this is the issue)
> - The Chocolatey Community Team may have blocked access due to excessive use - see excessive use for details

Comment: Thanks for the link to the troubleshooting article. I managed to retrieve the IP with the help of [this post](https://superuser.com/a/722397/329913), however the IP changes with each build and none of the ones I've tried were blocked. I can't really test the other things since I don't have direct access to the Travis build slaves. I'm pretty sure it's the Unity Server delivering 403 rather than Chocolatey. I've already posted in the Travis forums, might try Unity as well..